# Spring JPA Save - How to get Generated ID value from table when INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger is used?

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an existing Microsoft SQL server table which has Primary key which is an Identity column. I am using Spring Crudrepository Save method to insert new record in this table. But this table has "Instead of Insert" trigger which actually inserts the data.

I can successfully insert a row but the Save returns an entity without setting the ID column and it is always 0.

Below is my column in the JPA entity with required annotations.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
private int Id;
```

Please let me know how to get Id in case a trigger is used.

Comment: you can check how to implement UUID for this case .Go through [this](https://xebia.com/blog/jpa-implementation-patterns-using-uuids-as-primary-keys/)

Comment: Thanks @VijayD. But unfortunately, I can't change the table schema.

Comment: Can you try to use sequence from database here, while inserting using trigger?

Comment: @VijayD Sorry, I am new to hibernate but can we use existing table identity key as Sequence without affecting other clients which would insert rows into this table?